# How to uninstall EF Core tables? Or how to remove all migrations ? Or how to call `dotnet ef database update 0` from user code?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-core-2.1, entity-framework-core-migrations

I'm developing web app and near it small command line application that install ef core tables in the DB. Last can be done calling `dbContext.Database.Migrate();` and this works.

Now I want to provide `unistall` option (with this app).

But how to remove migrations (means call functionality of `dotnet ef database update 0` from my code) ?

It could be not one command call (as it was in case with `dbContext.Database.Migrate();`). But snippet with loop through all migrations in migrations assembly and call of 'Downs'.

Comment: Is this somewhat close to what you are looking for: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jan/13/Resetting-Entity-Framework-Migrations-to-a-clean-Slate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EF Core provides publicly only the `dbContext.Database.Migrate();` extension method used to migrate the latest version. It's mentioned in the [Applying migrations at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/index#applying-migrations-at-runtime) section of the EF Core documentation, which also contains the following

> **Note**
>
> This method builds on top of the `IMigrator` service, which can be used for more advanced scenarios. Use `DbContext.GetService<IMigrator>()` to access it.

which gives you the solution, because [`IMigrator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.imigrator) interface provides `Migrate` method accepting optional `targetMigration` parameter with the same semantics as the `dotnet ef database update` or `Update-Database` PM commands. Passing `"0"` (which is the value of the `Migration.InitialDatabase` constant) will perform the operation in question.

You'll need the following additional `using`s:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
```

and code like this:

```
var migrator = dbContext.GetService<IMigrator>();
migrator.Migrate(Migration.InitialDatabase);
```