# Entity Framework Core - Remove Migration programmatically

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Is there some way to run Remove-Migration / Update-Database 0 programmatically?

I am able to get a list of Migrations and to run pending Migrations using

```
context.Database.GetMigrations();
```

and

```
context.Database.Migrate();
```

Comment: For  the second part (`Update`), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52064291/how-to-uninstall-ef-core-tables-or-how-to-remove-all-migrations-or-how-to-cal. For `Remove` I don't think it is possible since it requires to modify the project.

Comment: migrations are part of your code and run statically - perhaps you should add a new one to remove the changes introduced by the one you want to remove.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev - the suggestion worked perfectly.